# React redux reducer not working correctly

Tags: reactjs

I have this reducer:

```
    case actionTypes.SET_ACTIVE:
      const editItem = accounts.map((item)=> item.id !== action.id ? item : {...item,active:!item.active})
      
      console.log(editItem)
          return {
            ...state,
            accounts: editItem
          }
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Lets say I have 2 items in the state array **accounts** all I want to achieve is **If one item.active is true and I click on second one,the first items item.active should change to false and the clicked items ite.active should change to true**

I tried to do this with filter but it did not work and came back to map

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate the items object, with active set to `false` for the items that do not match the clicked items.

```
case actionTypes.SET_ACTIVE:
      const editItem = accounts.map((item)=> item.id !== action.id ? {...item,active: false} : {...item,active: true})
      
      console.log(editItem)
          return {
            ...state,
            accounts: editItem
          }
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

PS: If possible , you should maintain a local state for each of your checkboxes and set that via a toggle function and then at some later point you want to dispatch.
I dont know, how you designed the application , but just an additional suggestion!

Comment: to simplify, you could do: `{ ...item, active: item.id === action.id ? true : false }`